# Mac Wireless is not working

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, vpn

I have (another) weird problem on my mac.

I have a wireless bridge at home, which works ok with my phone and other computers. 
But on my mac, it behaves in a weird way. 
I can connect to it, but I cannot use it with any browser. I can ping Google successfully but I cannot access the same website on the browser. 
If I try to connect to it through a vpn (as I am doing now) then all works ok.

In addition, I only get problems at night as in the morning it works fine (probably this is due to traffic, but it might also related to the fact that my wife is using the bridge already, although as I said I have no problem with the other devices).

Answer (score 1):

If your browser or OS was configured to use your company's Web (HTTP) Proxy server, then it wouldn't work when you're not on your company's network.  VPN'ing into your company's network would allow it to work again.

So check your OS `System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Proxies` and your browsers (I believe Firefox uses its own proxy settings rather than honor the OS X system settings) to make sure they're not set to use a web proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I don't think that is the problem. I did not mention that the problem does not occur if  do not use the wireless bridge, but I connect directly to the wireless router.